# Why is Django forbidding having multiple leafs in the migration graph?

Tags: django, django-migrations

### Immediate problem

What is the reason that Django refuses to migrate when there are multiple leafs in the migration graph ? I assume the reason is similar to what is described in the [SQLAlchemy docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/branches.html) :

> the challenge of a branch is to merge the branches into a single series of changes, so that databases established from either source tree individually can be upgraded to reference the merged result equally.

In other words, if we do not have to deal with multiple databases being in different HEADS, what other possible problems could arise when we have multiple leafs (apart from the application order of the migrations not being fully defined) ?

I run the migrate command after modifying django to not perform this check, and no issue arise.

However, this usecase does not seem to be supported in django, as there is no way to override the check behaviour other than monkeypatching / using a forked django.

### Why I'm asking

we are implementing a mechanism to handle no-downtime migrations on Django application. In particular, we are dealing with long running migrations, that we would like to apply separately from short running migrations.

This means we have two sets of migrations that are applied independently, each having their own HEAD.

We have a custom mechanism to run only the migrations of the given type. However, the migrate command fails with

> Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph:.To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge

when there are multiple leafs.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue recently. It occurred in the default auth table. Running a merge didnt resolve the issue. My problem was that in the auth. 0001-inital this table had a field first_name where max_length was set to 30. (I had created a custom user model). Later in the django_migrations table list was 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length.py migration that wanted to reset this value to 150 (In my case this was somehow related to the setup of the group_permissions table).  This obviously causes a conflict with the initial setup for the custom user model. I simply edited the second migration file to correspond to the initial setup value and reran the migrations without a merge. I suggest you use mysqlworkbench and get a list of the migrations in django_migrations or in the terminal run python manage.py makemigrations followed by django manage.py showmigrations. Then open each of these migration files in an editor like vscode (the ones without the 'x' using the terminal) and try to find any duplications or differences in assigned values between the initial.py migration and subsequent ones. You might also need to check the files listed at the top of the migrations file under dependencies. The dependency files might also have conflicting values assigned to field names.